# Why does the limit of circle is always taken as $2\pi$?

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors

I noticed in a couple of integration problems which asked to find the work done across the circular path but in all the cases regardless of the radius of the circle e.g:

$$x^2+y^2=9$$

the limit was still taken from $0$ to $2\pi$.

$$\int_0^{2\pi} F \cdot dr$$

Why is it not $2\pi r$ depending on the radius?

Comment: Don't you mean $\int_{\gamma} F \cdot dr$ which is a line integral (where $\gamma$ is the circle centered at the origin of radius 3)?

Comment: Or maybe you mean $\int_0^{2\pi}F.d\theta$ ?

Comment: The $0$ to $2\pi$ part in any integral related to a circle (or maybe a sphere or something else) is there to cover all angles and thus all directions in space. The $0$ to $r$ part is there to cover all distances from the origin to $r$; like this you have traced out your whole integration domain. Remember that integrals are just disguised sums, and you are summing the value of your integrand over all parts of your domain. Of course, you still need to answer these other two questions to make this question well-defined.

Comment: @IanMiller: Yes, upon substituting the values for $x = 3cos \theta$ and $y = 3sin \theta$ it becomes this. So, I guess $2\pi$ is there cover just the angles?

Comment: Yes. The radius is taken into account in the $x$ and $y$ that you substitute into $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a function $F(x,y)$ which describes the tangental force applied at each point on the circular path then the work done is given by:
$$\int_C F\space ds$$
We can change this from a line integral over $C$ to an integral over the angles:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}F(x,y)\space r d\theta$$

Comment: Does $\times$ denote a cross-product ?

Comment: No I was just meaning regular multiple. There isn't a need for vectors there.

Comment: Your notation is confusing, as is the dot.

Comment: Criticism accepted. Notation improved.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that this is a shortcut notation for the line integral, as said by MathNewbie in comments.

Along a circle, you have $r=(R\cos(\theta),R\sin(\theta))$ and

$$\oint_\gamma F\cdot dr=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}(-F_xR\sin(\theta)+F_yR\cos(\theta))\,d\theta.$$